# Joining query upon first result only

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I am creating a stored procedure where I would like to bring back just the first record from each match up instead every record that matches.

I have written the following code so far:

```
SELECT
    Tenant.FirstNames AS LeadTenantFirstName, Tenant.LastNames AS LeadTenantLastNames,
    Deposit.CertificateNumber AS DPCNumber

    FROM tblMemberPropertyDepositTenantHistory AS Tenant
    INNER JOIN tblMemberPropertyDeposits AS Deposit 
    ON Tenant.MemberPropertyDepositID = Deposit.MemberPropertyDepositID
```

The problem is that it will bring back a record for every tenant in the query for a certificate, but I would like to bring back just the first tenant created for each certificate?

Any ideas?

Comment: is Deposit.CertificateNumber the only column you need from the tblMemberPropertyDeposits  table?

whats the logic to choose between the possible values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you right you need something like this:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Tenant.MemberPropertyDepositID ORDER BY Tenant.MemberPropertyDepositID) AS RowNbr,
        Tenant.MemberPropertyDepositID,
        Tenant.FirstNames,
        Tenant.LastNames
    FROM
        tblMemberPropertyDepositTenantHistory AS Tenant
)
SELECT
    Tenant.FirstNames AS LeadTenantFirstName, 
    Tenant.LastNames AS LeadTenantLastNames,
    Deposit.CertificateNumber AS DPCNumber
FROM 
    tblMemberPropertyDeposits AS Deposit 
    LEFT JOIN CTE AS Tenant
        ON Tenant.MemberPropertyDepositID=Deposit.MemberPropertyDepositID
        AND Tenant.RowNbr=1
```

Comment: This worked absolutely perfectly and performance is great. Thank you very much

Comment: Glad to help. You might also know that I used a Left join insted of a inner join. That is because if there is no rows a inner join will filter away the rows that are null. A left join will still bring the tenants. The row number is also a better pick then using max or min in a join and CTE function makes it easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

I assume tblMemberPropertyDepositTenantHistory (Deposit) has a primary key:

```
SELECT
    Tenant.FirstNames AS LeadTenantFirstName, Tenant.LastNames AS LeadTenantLastNames,
    Deposit.CertificateNumber AS DPCNumber
    FROM tblMemberPropertyDepositTenantHistory AS Tenant
    INNER JOIN tblMemberPropertyDeposits AS Deposit 
    ON Deposit.PrimaryKey = (
        SELECT MIN(tblMemberPropertyDepositTenantHistory.PrimaryKey)
        FROM tblMemberPropertyDepositTenantHistory
        WHERE tblMemberPropertyDepositTenantHistory.MemberPropertyDepositID = 
                Tenant.MemberPropertyDepositID
    )
```